# Incorrect output after entering a series of number

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;
    // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
    if (std::cin >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1; // store the count for the current value we're processing
        while (std::cin >> val) { // read the remaining numbers
            if (val == currVal) // if the values are the same
                ++cnt; // add 1 to cnt
            else { // otherwise, print the count for the previous value
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
                        << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                currVal = val; // remember the new value
                cnt = 1; // reset the counter
            }
        } // while loop ends here
        // remember to print the count for the last value in the file
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
                << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
    } // outermost if statement ends here
    return 0;
}
```

My input

```
42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100
```

Result should be:

```
42 occurs 5 times
55 occurs 2 times
62 occurs 1 times
100 occurs 3 times
```

But actual output is:

```
 42 occurs 5 times
```

Could someone please point out what mistake am I making?

Comment: Seriously, this is a 4 line program using `std::map<int, int>`.

Comment: dude im new to c++, take it easy man chill @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: This works as expected on my machine

Comment: This works as expected, with gcc 5.3.1 on Linux x86-64. There's nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: @dzjustinli See here: http://ideone.com/ZbotLP  Also, if the numbers repeat but are not consecutive, you will get a problem.  For example `42 42 9 42`  http://ideone.com/k4IUJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this on a Windows system and typed your input into the command prompt, and it gave me the following output:

```
42 occurs 5 times
55 occurs 2 times
62 occurs 1 times
```

The issue here is that you're still in the while loop, so your last std:cout statement hasn't executed yet. If you are typing your input into the command prompt of your program and pressing ENTER, then you'll continue looping until std:cin returns false. You can verify this by typing more numbers into your program after it gives you the output, and then pressing ENTER again. You'll continue looping until std:cin returns false, which it will do if you put anything other than a number at the end of your input.